# Rebasing into feature branch

Tags: git

If I'm working on a feature branch for a long period of time (weeks) and I want to regularly rebase master into my branch, should I always switch to master, pull latest, then switch back to the feature branch and rebase master?

Comment: Sure but there is no need to switch to master in order to fetch and merge master. So your first three steps can be one step!

Comment: what would that command look like?

Comment: You would say `git fetch origin master:master`.

Comment: Incidentally there is no such thing as rebase into. You do not rebase master. You rebase your feature branch onto master. So your title is wrong and every sentence involving the word rebase is wrong. Your mental picture of Git may be wrong too.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. I'll dig deeper into trying to fill my knowledge gaps on this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would simply do, assuming I am already on the feature branch:

```
git fetch && git rebase origin/master
```

You could, as commented, fetch only `master` with `git fetch origin master:master`, but I prefer fetching everything to have a complete local representation of the remote repository.

And since you are not working on `master` directly, you can ignore `master`, and rebase on top of `origin/master`, which was updated by the fetch.

Comment: I'm curious how this works. `git fetch` does not change local `master` in any way, so how does this help move the feature branch further along `master`? (My answer, on the other hand, does a fast forward of `master`, so `master` is advanced and the feature branch is advanced by the rebase.)

Comment: @matt Good point. I forgot `origin/` in `git rebase origin/master`. I have edited the answer accordingly, and explained my reasoning.

Comment: Dumb question, but doesn't fetch just grab the metedata? It not going to actually update my feature branch with the latest, right?

Comment: @RyanW. fetch update by default all remote tracking branches, including `origin/master`: `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`: see https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec